# Related words persisting longer in a language than their etymology would otherwise suggest

Tags: etymology, evolution, evolutionary-linguistics

I was considering the “a” prefix as in afoot, aflame, alight. That prefix is largely in disuse in conversational English. But two notable exceptions, “asleep” and “awake” make me wonder if there’s a broader principle at work. “Asleep” and “awake” are antipodal antonyms and it seems logical that it may be harder for them to fall into disuse as they would need to do so together.

Unfortunately, for the life of me, I can’t come up with any other examples – at least not in language. In evolution, however, you see something similar: interdependent genes tend to evolve more slowly than more independent genes as both need to evolve together.

Can anyone think of other examples of this? Is this part of a more general linguistic principle?

Comment: What do genes have to do with this? There are many others, here's part of the OED list: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/afoot_adv?tl=true

Comment: The prefix _a-_ is no longer really **productive** in English (meaning we don’t usually form new words with it), but it’s by no means “in disuse”. There are many, many words containing it that remain in common use: aback, aboard, abreast, abroad, about, across, adrift, afar, afloat, agape, ahead, ajar, akimbo, akin, alive, alike, aloft, aloud, amid, amiss, among, arise, around, arouse, ashore, aside, askew, aslant, atop… just to name a few. Apart from asleep/awake and perhaps aboard/ashore, none of them seem to have any particular antonymic relation to one another.

Comment: "a" means more than one thing. Anyway, asleep and awake are not like: afoot, aflame, alight.